# Hash table with two primary keys

Tags: c#, collections, primary-key, hashtable

Using `System.Collections` how to create a collection with two primary keys ?

I mean new entries with the same combination are avoided but each key can be used with other keys (like combining two primary keys in `SQL`)

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is Composite Key or Compound Key. A key with two attributes is still just ONE key, not two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use a `struct`, example:

```
struct CompositeKey<T1,T2>
{
  public T1 Item1;
  public T2 Item2;
}
```

Then use that as the key.

Comment: Note that structs might not work as intended if you're using a Dictionary for performance reasons. See "[How does native implementation of ValueType.GetHashCode work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5927853/579344)".

Comment: @johv: Hash codes need not be unique, also .NET handles a few collisions quite fast. Many collisions obviously will be an issue.

Comment: I find the default implementation for structs quite surprising and non-intuitive. I had expected something closer to what Tuples provide.

Comment: @johv: And then we can compare anonymous types too :) My way was just to show a very easy way that should be good 95% of time.

Comment: But is it really "good 95% of time"? How would the hashcode of a struct with two strings be calculated? Using just the first of the strings? I guess you're correct if by 95% of the time, you mean when linear search access time is okay.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) if you're using .NET 4.0.

Else you can create a Tuple by yourself.

Found on StackOverFlow : [Tuples( or arrays ) as Dictionary keys in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955982/tuples-or-arrays-as-dictionary-keys-in-c)

```
struct Tuple<T, U, W> : IEquatable<Tuple<T,U,W>>
{
    readonly T first;
    readonly U second;
    readonly W third;

    public Tuple(T first, U second, W third)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }

    public T First { get { return first; } }
    public U Second { get { return second; } }
    public W Third { get { return third; } }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return first.GetHashCode() ^ second.GetHashCode() ^ third.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((Tuple<T, U, W>)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(Tuple<T, U, W> other)
    {
        return other.first.Equals(first) && other.second.Equals(second) && other.third.Equals(third);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like LaGrandMere said, you can use [System.Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) if you're on .NET 4.0 or later:

```
Tuple<int,string> key = Tuple.Create(0, "Test");
```

Also, note that if you're putting strings, ints etc as keys in dictionaries you're going to have to special-case what would've been NULL in SQL. Can't have a null-key in a Dictionary.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, int>, string>();

var address1 = Tuple.Create("5th Avenue",15);
var address2 = Tuple.Create("5th Avenue",25);
var address3 = Tuple.Create("Dag Hammarskjölds väg", 4);

dict[address1] = "Donald";
dict[address2] = "Bob";
dict[address3] = "Kalle";

// ...

int number = Int32.Parse("25");
var addressKey = Tuple.Create("5th Avenue",number);
string name = dict[addressKey]; // Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also construct composite key and use that in dictionary

```
var compositeKey = key1.ToString()+key2.ToString();

var dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
dict.Add(compositekey,val);
```