# How do the GetHashCode methods work for the value types in C#?

Tags: c#

Can I ever expect the same hash code for situations where an integer has the same value, but it is cast to a different integer type?

What about for floating point numbers?

Comment: I'm kind of curious why you care. `GetHashCode` is really only intended for implementing hash lists (e.g. `Dictionary<T>`). You should never care about the specific values that `GetHashCode` returns, only about their "quality".

Comment: I realize this is probably trivia, but I found it interesting to see how these methods work anyways.  Reason: In a bit of code i am working on I am looking at storing values in , and up-converting them based on user demand.  So for example, if a user puts integers in the list initially, and then at some point later in the program they want to put in longs, the list gets upconverted... the problem is, the hashcodes for items in the list would have to have been calculated based on the promoted type initially, otherwise the hashcodes for the sequence will change from the upconversion.

Comment: Please be sure to wrap code-like things in \`backticks\` so they are not misinterpreted.

Comment: You should edit your question  so it does not look like duplicate of existing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926776/how-does-native-implementation-of-valuetype-gethashcode-work (and similar...)... Also Similar to your previous question it is strictly for entertainment/education as one should not rely on particular implementation of GetHashCode nor try to compare hash codes for different types.

Comment: Is one of the purposes of this site not education?

Answer (score 2):

In some cases for a pair of identical values an integer cast from one type to another will return the same hash code, 
but this behaviour should not be relied on.

For a pair of values where the same number represented as a float and as a double, the value will be (always?) be different.

from the microsoft source code page:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

UInt16.GetHashCode:

```
internal ushort m_value;
// Returns a HashCode for the UInt16
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return (int)m_value;
}
```

Int16.GetHashCode:

```
internal short m_value;
// Returns a HashCode for the Int16
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return ((int)((ushort)m_value) | (((int)m_value) << 16));
}
```

UInt32.GetHashCode:

```
internal uint m_value;
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return ((int) m_value);
}
```

Int32.GetHashCode:

```
internal int m_value;
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return m_value;
}
```

Int64.GetHashCode:

```
internal long m_value;
// The value of the lower 32 bits XORed with the uppper 32 bits.
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return (unchecked((int)((long)m_value)) ^ (int)(m_value >> 32));
}
```

UInt64.GetHashCode

```
internal ulong m_value;
// The value of the lower 32 bits XORed with the uppper 32 bits.
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return ((int)m_value) ^ (int)(m_value >> 32);
}
```

Double.GetHashCode

```
internal double m_value;
//The hashcode for a double is the absolute value of the integer representation
//of that double.
//
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
public unsafe override int GetHashCode() {
    double d = m_value;
    if (d == 0) {
        // Ensure that 0 and -0 have the same hash code
        return 0;
    }
    long value = *(long*)(&d);
    return unchecked((int)value) ^ ((int)(value >> 32));
}
```

Single.GetHashCode

```
internal float m_value;
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public unsafe override int GetHashCode() {
    float f = m_value;
    if (f == 0) {
        // Ensure that 0 and -0 have the same hash code
        return 0;
    }
    int v = *(int*)(&f);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: +1 for *"this behaviour should not be relied on"*, which should be written in a red blinking bold font :-)