# Getting Value from dictionary, when the key in an object

Tags: c#

I have an object PixelData:

```
public class PixelData
{
   public int X {get;set;}
   public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

pixel data is a key to a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<PixelData, int> dict
```

how do i use pixel data the right way?

Comment: Well as you haven't overridden `Equals` or `GetHashCode`, you'd need to have a reference to the original `PixelData` object used as the key. Additionally, even if you *did* override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, you'd have a mutable key which is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to use a [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct) instead of a class for `PixelData`:

```
public struct PixelData
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

var dict = new Dictionary<PixelData, int>();
```

You can read about the differences between structs and classes in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275/7662085). Short version: structs are *value* types, unlike classes which are *reference* types. Therefore, if you want to retrieve a value from the dictionary, you don't need a reference to the original `PixelData` instance which was used as the key. You can go ahead and create a new instance, with the exact same `X` and `Y` you used for the key, and it will work just fine.

```
// Add new value to dictionary with new PixelData instance as the key
dict.Add(new PixelData { X = 1, Y = 1 }, 42); 

// Retrieving the value using a new, but identical instance of PixelData works just fine
int value = dict[new PixelData { X = 1, Y = 1 }]);
```

Comment: Mutable structs are evil.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/441357/3312
https://techiesimon.com/2017/02/18/mutable-structs-are-evil-yes-really/
http://www.tigranetworks.co.uk/blogs/electricdreams/the-evil-of-mutable-structs/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/

Comment: You'd also want to override gethashcode for efficiency I believe.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Are you sure? It worked fine as is when I tested it out

Comment: It will work fine, just possibly not as fast as it could be.

Comment: It turns out that since the struct contains only value types you don't need to override gethashcode. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5927853/

Comment: Jesse, you are usually right, but in this case, keys are rarely changed. Thank you all guys.

Comment: So why not just make them immutable?

Answer (score -1):

If X and Y are public properties, then below query can be used to retrieve the matching dictionary value. This query assumes that 'searchingForItem' is the PixelData Item, you are looking to find in dict.

var matchingItem = dict.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key.X.Equals(searchingForItem.X) && p.Key.Y.Equals(searchingForItem.Y));

Comment: That seems like a pretty topsy-turvy way to use a dictionary ;-)