# What really defines the result of typeof(MyType).GetHashCode()?

Tags: c#, .net

I maneuvered myself into a situation that breaks DependencyInjection.

Most likely it's related to the fact that I load assemblies left and right and tried to build a modular application that can run a ASP.NET minimal API from a dynamically loaded assembly that itself can load additional services from other assemblies.

So at one point I add a Singleton to a service collection like `services.AddSingleton<IKDFService, KDFService>();` but the ASP.NET endpoint cannot resolve that service, even though it exists in the `ServiceProvider`.

It all boils down to the fact that the `ServiceProvider` uses `ServiceIdentifier` internally for `Dictionary` keys and `ServiceIdentifier` implements `IEquatable` [using the `GetHashCode()` of the `Type` that is about to be resolved](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceLookup/ServiceIdentifier.cs#L53).

And this `GetHashCode()` on the type returns a different result from the type I originally add to the `ServiceCollection`.

Since I'm already at 15ish projects in the solution, giving you an overview is hard. There's a console application loading assemblies that can act as program entry points, but also some, possibly the same assemblies, that provides services that run in their own thread. The program entry points themself load assemblies (e.g. for providing API endpoints), etc.

I've tried different ways of assembly loading, e.g. `Assembly.Load()`, `Assembly.LoadFile()`, `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath()`, etc. Before starting ASP.NET as well at the endpoint itself `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` report the questionable assembly only once.

So while I don't expect anyone to help me assist in this madness I've created, I'd highly appreciate anyone who can tell me more about situations in which `typeof(MyType).GetHashCode()` can produce different results during the same application run though called from different assemblies. Thank you!

PS: I'm on net8-rc1

Comment: First thing I'd do is log or inspect the `AssemblyQualifiedName` of each of those `typeof(MyType)`s.

Comment: Do you maybe have a hashcode collision? Does `typeof(Foo).GetHashcode()` equal `typeof(Bar).GetHashcode()` perhaps?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of question better server by a discussion in the runtime repo.

Comment: I suspect the answer to your actual question is "two types with identical name would be different if loaded from different assemblies/same assembly but different context (i.e., if you load the same assembly twice using LoadFrom it should, to my knowledge, generate that behavior).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's what I was trying to rule out by using different loading mechanisms (see [this great Issue comment for details](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39783#issuecomment-662735619)). Using these, I managed that `AppDomain` reported the type-providing assembly only once.

Yet the assembly is also loaded by the runtime as it's a project reference of the ExecutingAssembly, so maybe there's still some double-loading going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @IanKemp I copied the text from the Issue draft I had open and ready to submit. Tried to be a good citizen by first asking somewhere else, but now I think this is either some kind of unsupported scenario, or a bug in DependencyInjection, which obviously relies on the implementation. So a good reason to open an issue actually....

Answer (score 1):

To stick with just the title question, the answer is we don't really know.

The `GetHashCode()` method is inherited from `Object`, but it was built in the expectation it will often be overridden. In this case we also need to clarify it's not looking for the method via `MyType`, but rather the special `System.Type` type itself.

According to the [.Net source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/type.cs), that method looks like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    Type SystemType = UnderlyingSystemType;
    if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(SystemType, this))
        return SystemType.GetHashCode();
    return base.GetHashCode();
}
```

This code leans heavily on `UnderlyingSystemType`, which it turns out is abstract and so not really predictable from the context available:

```
// The behavior of UnderlyingSystemType varies from type to type.
// For IReflect objects: Return the underlying Type that represents the IReflect Object.
// For expando object: this is the (Object) IReflectInstance.GetType().  For Type object it is this.
// It could also return the baked type or the underlying enum type in RefEmit. See the comment in
// code:TypeBuilder.SetConstantValue.
public abstract Type UnderlyingSystemType {
    get;
}
```

I can say it's likely to end up back at the basic implementation on System.Object, which points to [`RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/runtimehelpers.cs), which in turn is marked `extern` and not otherwise documented.

We could use a decompiler to look at actual behavior (and people have done this!), but the lack of documentation means MS is free to change the behavior at any time. While it's unlikely to change in a meaningful way any time soon, it's still unwise to depend on a specific implementation.

Comment: Side note: for "he basic implementation on object" you seem to be mixing up record types (that include fields into GetHashCode)... for just object it is roughly address comparison... and for value types is "a single field comparison" (according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926776/how-does-native-implementation-of-valuetype-gethashcode-work)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe a little better now.