# Best approach to multi-part int dictionary key?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, key

Say my dictionary needs to be keyed by a combination of ItemId and RegionId, both int.  And say the type of the value side is "Data".
I could do this a couple of ways:

Way 1: multi-level dictionary, like this:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Data>>  myData;
```

so a lookup could be coded like this:

```
Data data1  = myData[itemId][regionId];
```

Not bad, but a drawback is that I would need to check for key existence at the first level, so safer code would be

```
Data data1 = null;
if (myData.ContainsKey(itemId)) data1 =  myData[itemId][regionId];
```

Way 2: use a multi-part key. 
In this approach I would create a struct  to represent the parts, and use a struct as the dictionary key:

```
private struct MultiPartKey
{
    public int ItemId;
    public int RegionId;
}

Dictionary<MultiPartKey, Data>  myData;
```

and a lookup would be like:

```
MultiPartKey mpk;
mpk.ItemId = itemId;
mpk.RegionId = regionId;
Data data1 = myData[mpk];
```

A possible disadvantage here is that it only works if my struct is composed entirely of simple value types, so that a bitwise comparison of two instances will be equal. 
(Right?)

What do you think?

Comment: Your key-class should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to allow comparison. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tuples( or arrays ) as Dictionary keys in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955982/tuples-or-arrays-as-dictionary-keys-in-c-sharp). **Also** [is-there-a-benefit-to-tuple-based-or-nested-dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908991/is-there-a-benefit-to-tuple-based-or-nested-dictionaries)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rather than make your struct "dumb" like that (and mutable) you can make it immutable and give it appropriate equality methods, e.g.

```
private struct MultiPartKey : IEquatable<MultiPartKey>
{
    private readonly int itemId;
    private readonly int regionId;

    public int ItemId { get { return itemId; } }
    public int RegionId { get { return regionId; } }

    public MultiPartKey(int itemId, int regionId)
    {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.regionId = regionId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + itemId;
        hash = hash * 31 + regionId;
        return hash;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return other is MultiPartKey ? Equals((MultiPartKey)other) : false;
    }

    public bool Equals(MultiPartKey other)
    {
        return itemId == other.itemId &&
               regionId == other.regionId;
    }
}
```

You can expand that to use whatever types you want, so long as you implement equality and hash code properly. Implementing `IEquatable<MultiPartKey>` means the dictionary won't need to box the keys in order to compare them.

The downside of using this approach instead of the `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Data>>` is that you can't easily find all entries for a given item ID.

Comment: thank you Jon and others for your responses, but within the constraint I stated (struct with only value-type members) I would not need to override equals or gethashcode would I? .Net equality on value types (such as struct) would be a bitwise comparison.

Comment: @Elroy: While you don't *have* to, I personally would. Aside from anything else, it will prevent boxing.

Comment: @Elroy: The other point is that then you *aren't* constrained to simple value types. Oh, and I seem to remember that the hash code generated by default for structs only uses the first field, which would be pretty rubbish in terms of hash collisions in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the `IEquatable<T>` tip. And yes, you remember correctly, from [ValueType.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.gethashcode.aspx): "One or more fields of the derived type is used to calculate the return value. If you call the derived type's GetHashCode method, the return value is not likely to be suitable for use as a key in a hash table."

Comment: It is OK to throw a `NullReferenceException` in `IEquatable<MultiPartKey>.Equals` method?

Comment: @astef: That isn't possible here - because `MultiPartKey` is a struct.

Answer (score 11):

Yet another way would be to use the *Tuple* class:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Data>  myData;
```

This works with up to eight values, provided they implement *Equals* and *GetHashCode*.