# How do I order results of a List<IDictionary> object using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Background

I have a workflow that constructs a set of dictionaries, each with identical KEYS, but (of course) various VALUES.  After these dictionaries are constructed, they are added to a common list.  I need to order that list based on a particular KEY in each dictionary.

I am using C#, .NET 4, LINQ, Lambdas, etc.

## Question

How do I order a list of dictionaries based on a common key property in each dictionary?  For example if I have the code below, how do I order based on the "Color" key?

```
IDictionary<String, object> item1 = new Dictionary<String, object>{"Color","Red"};
IDictionary<String, object> item2 = new Dictionary<String, object>{"Color","Blue"};
IDictionary<String, object> item3 = new Dictionary<String, object>{"Color","Green"};

var dictionaryList = new List<IDictionary<String, object>>();

dictionaryList.add(item1);
dictionaryList.add(item2);
dictionaryList.add(item3);

var orderedList = dictionaryList.OrderBy[??????];
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could instead use a [`List<Tuple>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) or [Dictionary with Tuples as key](http://stackoverflow.com/a/956043/284240).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I am missing something?

```
var orderedList = dictionaryList.OrderBy(d => d["Color"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the OrderBy method a function that given a `Dictionary<String, object>` returns the item you wish to order by, so:

```
var orderedList = dictionaryList.OrderBy(d => d["Color"]);
```

Will suffice.

As an aside, you can clean up the initialisation a little bit like so:

```
var orderedList = new[] { item1, item2, item3 }.OrderBy(d => d["Color"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `d => d["Color"]`.