# Dictionary values are not correctly updated during a while loop

Tags: c#, dictionary, while-loop, backtracking, sudoku

I am currently attempting to write a Chronological Backtracking Algorithem for a sudoku solver. I have several positions stored as FlexiblePositions, which is represented as two integer in an array. Each value is stored in a dictionary with a list of numbers from 1 to 9.

The algorithem takes the location, fills it in the dictionary and gets the list of possible numbers (domain.) He is supposed to take a number, check it with the Checker Boolean method, and then remove it. If the domain is empty he moves in to the previous location.

However when he takes the domain, he doesnt seam to take the domain from the dictionary, only using one list for the entire run from the algorithm.

I don't know how I can cause the loop to take the domain which I request it too take.

```
int[,] ChronologicalBacktracking(int[,] s, List<int[]>FlexPositions)
{
    var domains = new Dictionary<int[], List<int>>();
    int[,] sudoku = (int[,])s.Clone();
    List<int> options = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    foreach (var i in FlexPositions)
    {
        domains.Add(i, options);
    }
    int pointer = 0;
    while(pointer<FlexPositions.Count())
    {
        int[] pos = FlexPositions[pointer];
        if (domains[pos].Count == 0)
        {
```

Here the code should fill up the list of the pos before, then move to the previous one, but he for the if check above he still uses the same domain list.

```
            domains[pos] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            pointer--;
            if (pointer>=0)
            {
                int[] prev = FlexPositions[pointer];
                sudoku[prev[0],prev[1]] = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
```

PrintList2 prints a list of all numbers in the list, which will diminish by a number for each iteration, despite pos being changed.

```
            pos = FlexPositions[pointer];
            PrintList2(domains[pos]);
            int number = domains[pos][domains[pos].Count-1];
            Console.WriteLine(pos[0] + "" + pos[1] + " " + number);
            //PrintSudoku(sudoku);

            if (Checker(sudoku, pos, number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pointer);
                sudoku[pos[0], pos[1]] = number;
                domains[pos].RemoveAt(domains[pos].Count-1);
                pointer++;

                if (pointer == FlexPositions.Count())
                {
                    return (sudoku);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                domains[pos].RemoveAt(domains[pos].Count-1);
            }


        }
        
    }
    return (sudoku);
}
```

I had similar issues with references in the past, so I think it is that. However I am not experienced with C# enough to fix this.
Additionally I know this code seams optimally, or might have other issues, as I still need to improve on it once I got it working, however I cant seam to solve the issue with my dictionary list not being updated correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tuples (or arrays) as Dictionary keys in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955982/tuples-or-arrays-as-dictionary-keys-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @shingo Not sure, are you suggesting the error is due to me using an array as Dictionary Key? Because my issues is more with the values stored by the Dictionary

Comment: Usually using an array as key is wrong, I'm not sure whether this is the issue. I don't quite understand the algorithm here. What does `Checker` do? Can you provide some input values?

Comment: @shingo I swapped the key around with a struct for position, but the error still persisits. Checker only checks if the number filled in at the location is allowed to be there. For example: my sudoku has a block with a 3 at location [0,3] so he fills in 9, checks if 9 is allowed, and if so fills it in and removes it. The issue is when he moves to the next location, he will continue with a list consisting of 1-8 instead of using a new list.

Comment: Oh, that's because you were using the only `options` list, you should create new list for each flex positions.