# Multi-key dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I know there isn't one in the BCL but can anyone point me to a good opensource one?

By Multi I mean 2 keys. ;-)

Comment: Do you want a key that is made of multiple attributes or do you want it possible so that the same key can exist more than once in the same dictionary?  These are different.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689940/hashtable-with-multidimensional-key-in-c

Comment: You might want to add an example usage, to clarify what you mean.

Comment: These are worth a look: http://noocyte.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/double-key-dictionary/ and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32894/C-Multi-key-Generic-Dictionary

Comment: no +1 for making the question this short and vague. Your question can be implied in 10 different ways

Comment: I wrote an answer for C# 7.0 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829428/531524

Comment: How is this question marked duplicate? The question referenced is for a door with multiple keyholes, while this question could just as well be a door with one keyhole and multiple keys

Comment: I wrote a [MultiKeyDictionary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MultiKeyCollections/) package for net472, net481, netstandard2.1, and net6.0.

Answer (score 76):

I've also used tuples as [jason in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171812/multi-key-dictionary-in-c/1171847#1171847) does.  However, I suggest you simply define a tuple as a struct:

```
public struct Tuple<T1, T2> {
    public readonly T1 Item1;
    public readonly T2 Item2;
    public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) { Item1 = item1; Item2 = item2;} 
}

public static class Tuple { // for type-inference goodness.
    public static Tuple<T1,T2> Create<T1,T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2) { 
        return new Tuple<T1,T2>(item1, item2); 
    }
}
```

You get immutability, `.GetHashcode` and `.Equals` for free, which (while you're waiting for C# 4.0) is nice 'n simple...

One **warning** however: the default `GetHashcode` implementation (sometimes) [only considers the first field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3842515/42921) so make sure to make the first field the most discriminating or implement `GetHashcode` yourself (e.g. using `FieldwiseHasher.Hash(this)` from [ValueUtils](http://eamonnerbonne.github.io/ValueUtils/)), otherwise you'll likely run into scalability issues.

Also, you get to avoid nulls which tend to complicate matters (and if you really want nulls, you just make your `Tuple<>` nullable).  Slightly offtopic, am I the only one annoyed at the framework-level lack of support for non-null references?  I work on large project, and occasionally a null creeps in somewhere it really shouldn't -- and hey presto, you get a nullreference exception -- but with a stack trace that points you to the reference's first usage, not the actually faulty code.

Of course, .NET 4.0 is pretty old by now; most of us can just use .NET 4.0's tuple.

***Edit:*** to workaround the poor `GetHashCode` implementation that .NET provides for structs I've written [ValueUtils](http://eamonnerbonne.github.io/ValueUtils/), which also allows you to use real names for your multi-field keys; that means you might write something like:

```
sealed class MyValueObject : ValueObject<MyValueObject> {
    public DayOfWeek day;
    public string NamedPart;
    //properties work fine too
}
```

...which hopefully makes it easier to have human-readable names for data with value semantics, at least until [some future version of C# implements proper tuples with named members](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347); hopefully with decent hashcodes ;-).

Comment: Nice blurb on reference versus value-type decision for tuples in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942829.aspx#id0400060

Comment: Indeed (after reading the article), if you use the default struct-implied .Equals and .GetHashcode implementation, a tuple with a double that's NaN will equal itself, even though double.NaN != double.NaN...

I can live with that.

Comment: That article says they used a reference type since didn't like causing confusing due to inconsistency of semantics between struct/reference types - but I don't see any argument as to why a reference type would thus be preferable; simply that you'd like all tuples to be of the same type.

Comment: You're not the only one that's annoyed by that. I read an article where one of the creators of C# and .NET said that support for non-null references was a feature that he really would have liked to included, but they (like the rest of us) were up against a deadline and couldn't fit that in, and now that the framework is in common use, I imagine it would be difficult to add support for that after-the-fact.

Comment: C# designers have already said they regret for the lack of support for non-nulls. Most probably in a new-born C#

Comment: This advice should be **heavily tempered** - the default implementation of [ValueType.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.gethashcode.aspx) can yield many collisions, which can lead to terrible Dictionary performance. It even says so: "If you call the derived type's GetHashCode method, the return value is not likely to be suitable for use as a key in a hash table". There's a great treatment of the subject by Eric Lippert of Microsoft [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841602/why-is-valuetype-gethashcode-implemented-like-it-is)

Comment: @bacar: that's a *very* good point, and one I've run into myself: I've included that warning in the answer.

Comment: @Eamon - It's actually worse than "only considers the first field" - sometimes it appears to consider *no* fields (despite what the documentation says)! See Jon Skeet's analysis/answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657348/new-keyvaluepairuint32-uint32i-j-gethashcode-high-rate-of-duplicates). He tests `KeyValuePair<ushort, uint>` (an example of a struct that doesn't override GetHashCode) and finds that it _appears_ to always return the same hash!

Comment: I don't think this answers the question at all - having a key composed of two items is not the same as having two indices

Comment: The question makes not mention of two indices - what are you referring to?

Comment: Getting `GetHashcode` and `Equals` for free is simple, but not nice. It comes with a performance penalty as internally the value equality is done using reflection. If it is a struct, one better implement `IEquatable<T>`.

Comment: @nawfal I've got an implementation of an expression-tree based implementation that efficiently and easily implements those for you, I'll have a look if I can get the OK to open source that.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne WoW, that will be great! Let me know if its written somewhere. I will try writing one myself too! :)

Comment: @nawfal: I decided to reimplement the hashcode function generator.  It works; but it's still pretty barebones: https://github.com/EamonNerbonne/ValueUtils

Comment: @EamonNerbonne looks good. I'm not very sure about `OverriddenHashCodeMethod`'s job. Will have to test.

Comment: @nawfal: I'll polish it up and add more features, and release it to nuget.  If you actually intend to use this, I'd love feedback on how to make it work for your usecase - feel free to comment on github!

Comment: @nawfal: OK, I think it's in a pretty usable state now.  I'd be interested in your opinion on two specific design issues: https://github.com/EamonNerbonne/ValueUtils/issues/1 and https://github.com/EamonNerbonne/ValueUtils/issues/2.  Even so, this is ready for real use - just try refering to nuget:ValueUtils, and create your class ala `sealed class MyClass : ValueObject<MyClass>`!  Early perf testing shows it to be much faster than ValueType, considerably faster than `Tuple<>`, and within a factor 2 of hand-rolled code.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne looks good, though using inheritance as code sharing mechanism is not all that good. I will inspect it in detail in sometime. May be a month :) Quite busy for this month. Nevertheless, thanks!

Answer (score 60):

I use a `Tuple` as the keys in a `Dictionary`.

```
public class Tuple<T1, T2> {
    public T1 Item1 { get; private set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; private set; }

    // implementation details
}
```

Be sure to override [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) and [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) and define `operator!=` and `operator==` as appropriate. You can expand the `Tuple` to hold more items as needed. .NET 4.0 will include a built-in `Tuple`.

Comment: Check out this blog post on performance tests between multiple "multi-key" dictionary implementations [here](http://www.fyslexicduck.com/2011/05/performance-tests-between-multiple.html)

Comment: @AronW The blog post never uses a `Tuple` as a key as far as I can tell?

Comment: If you're going to write your own Tuple class, may as well use named items instead of T1, T2...

Answer (score 38):

Tuples will be (are) in .Net 4.0 Until then, you can also use a

```
 Dictionary<key1, Dictionary<key2, TypeObject>>
```

or, creating a custom collection class to represent this...

```
 public class TwoKeyDictionary<K1, K2, T>: 
        Dictionary<K1, Dictionary<K2, T>> { }
```

or, with three keys...

```
public class ThreeKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, T> :
    Dictionary<K1, Dictionary<K2, Dictionary<K3, T>>> { }
```

Comment: Brilliant answer -- this worked perfectly for my needs.

Comment: This is not multi-key dictionary, this is quite bad implementation of a tupled-key dictionary, because you can't access values by second key, neither you can access them without it (unless you get it by Values of inner dictionary, but it can contain multiple items). Also, your solution lacks code for adding and removing items.

Comment: jeeez...  I'm not even sure what you are talking about. You want a multi-keyed dictionary to be able to access objects with *either* of the keys? That is in no way equivalent to a tuple as requested by the op. To your second, you really expect a fully fleshed out professional implementation, with all the bells and whistles, as an answer to the question? Dream on, I get paid for that. Write your own code.

Answer (score 26):

Many good solutions here,
What I am missing here is an implementation based on the build in `Tuple` type, so I wrote one myself.

Since it just inherits from `Dictionary<Tuple<T1,T2>, T>` you can always use both ways.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int, Row>();
var row = new Row();
dict.Add(1, 2, row);
dict.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2, row));
dict.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2));
```

here is the code.

```
public class Dictionary<TKey1,TKey2,TValue> :  Dictionary<Tuple<TKey1, TKey2>, TValue>, IDictionary<Tuple<TKey1, TKey2>, TValue>
{

    public TValue this[TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2]
    {
        get { return base[Tuple.Create(key1, key2)]; }
        set { base[Tuple.Create(key1, key2)] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, TValue value)
    {
        base.Add(Tuple.Create(key1, key2), value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2)
    {
        return base.ContainsKey(Tuple.Create(key1, key2));
    }
}
```

Please be aware that this implementation depends on the Tuple.Equals() implementation itself:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270346(v=vs.110).aspx

The obj parameter is considered to be equal to the current instance under the following conditions:

- It is a Tuple object.
- Its two components are of the same types as the current instance.
- Its two components are equal to those of the current instance. Equality is determined by the default object equality comparer for each component.

Comment: Simple and works well, thanks.

Comment: Very nice solution

Answer (score 15):

I wrote and have used this with success.

```
public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, V> : Dictionary<K1, Dictionary<K2, V>>  {

    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2] {
        get {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1) || !this[key1].ContainsKey(key2))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            return base[key1][key2];
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new Dictionary<K2, V>();
            this[key1][key2] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new Dictionary<K2, V>();
            this[key1][key2] = value;
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2);
    }

    public new IEnumerable<V> Values {
        get {
            return from baseDict in base.Values
                   from baseKey in baseDict.Keys
                   select baseDict[baseKey];
        }
    } 

}


public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, V> : Dictionary<K1, MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, V>> {
    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3] {
        get {
            return ContainsKey(key1) ? this[key1][key2, key3] : default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, V>();
            this[key1][key2, key3] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2, key3);
    }
}

public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, K4, V> : Dictionary<K1, MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, V>> {
    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4] {
        get {
            return ContainsKey(key1) ? this[key1][key2, key3, key4] : default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, V>();
            this[key1][key2, key3, key4] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2, key3, key4);
    }
}

public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, V> : Dictionary<K1, MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, V>> {
    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5] {
        get {
            return ContainsKey(key1) ? this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5] : default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, V>();
            this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2, key3, key4, key5);
    }
}

public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, V> : Dictionary<K1, MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, V>> {
    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6] {
        get {
            return ContainsKey(key1) ? this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6] : default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, V>();
            this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6] = value;
        }
    }
    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2, key3, key4, key5, key6);
    }
}

public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, V> : Dictionary<K1, MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, V>> {
    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7] {
        get {
            return ContainsKey(key1) ? this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7] : default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, V>();
            this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7] = value;
        }
    }
    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7);
    }
}

public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, V> : Dictionary<K1, MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, V>> {
    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7, K8 key8] {
        get {
            return ContainsKey(key1) ? this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8] : default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, V>();
            this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8] = value;
        }
    }
    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7, K8 key8) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8);
    }
}

public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, V> : Dictionary<K1, MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, V>> {
    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7, K8 key8, K9 key9] {
        get {
            return ContainsKey(key1) ? this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9] : default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, V>();
            this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9] = value;
        }
    }
    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7, K8 key8, K9 key9) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9);
    }
}

public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, K10, V> : Dictionary<K1, MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, K10, V>> {
    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7, K8 key8, K9 key9, K10 key10] {
        get {
            return ContainsKey(key1) ? this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9, key10] : default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, K10, V>();
            this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9, key10] = value;
        }
    }
    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7, K8 key8, K9 key9, K10 key10) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9, key10);
    }
}

public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, K10, K11, V> : Dictionary<K1, MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, K10, K11, V>> {
    public V this[K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7, K8 key8, K9 key9, K10 key10, K11 key11] {
        get {
            return ContainsKey(key1) ? this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9, key10, key11] : default(V);
        }
        set {
            if (!ContainsKey(key1))
                this[key1] = new MultiKeyDictionary<K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, K10, K11, V>();
            this[key1][key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9, key10, key11] = value;
        }
    }
    public bool ContainsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, K4 key4, K5 key5, K6 key6, K7 key7, K8 key8, K9 key9, K10 key10, K11 key11) {
        return base.ContainsKey(key1) && this[key1].ContainsKey(key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9, key10, key11);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote a `ToMultiKeyDictionary()` extension for this answer and [posted it as an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21270886/435383)

Comment: This works great in Unity where Tuple is not available!!! Note that u need `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Works well when both values put together function as a unique key.

Answer (score 9):

I frequently use this because it's short and provides the syntactic sugar I need...

```
public class MultiKeyDictionary<T1, T2, T3> : Dictionary<T1, Dictionary<T2, T3>>
{
    new public Dictionary<T2, T3> this[T1 key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!ContainsKey(key))
                Add(key, new Dictionary<T2, T3>());

            Dictionary<T2, T3> returnObj;
            TryGetValue(key, out returnObj);

            return returnObj;
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
dict[cat][fish] = 9000;
```

where the "Cat" key doesn't have to exist either.

Comment: I should also mention that it's arbitrary to create further nestings with another class <T1, T2, T3, T4> : Dictionary<T1, MultiKeyDictionary<T2, T3>>, etc. Also, I avoid using it, but it cleans up funky nested dictionaries pretty well.

Comment: What's a good way to check if the [cat][fish] or [cat][mouse] keys exist?

Comment: @goku_da_master `dict[cat].ContainsKey(mouse)` where if cat doesn't exist, you always get false, because it is newed up then. If you're using it this way a lot I would benchmark it though--it's not going to be a very optimized way of doing this.

Comment: Underrated solution! (: Very handy when using .NET earlier than 4.0.

Answer (score 7):

I'm currently simply concatenating the keys into a single string as a workaround. Of course, this will not work on non-string keys. Would love to know the answer as well.

Comment: Why not .ToString() the non-string keys?

Comment: Because on most class .ToSting() will be the same for all values (ie. the types name). Not all types have a valid string representation, etc, etc.

Comment: Yes, but you can usually override ToString in those classes.

Comment: Then, one cannot use sealed classes as keys, and instead of implementing one class which is a tuple of many, one must subclass many classes.

Comment: Yeah, too many BCL classes don't implement ToString, which means you can't assume ToString will return a unique representation of a given type's state.  TL;DR: fail

Comment: Using string concatenation can be dangerous. For example, if you have ints 123 and 456, and concatenate them to create a key, this would give "123456". If you have 12 and 3456 and you concatenate them, you get... "123456". Oops.

Comment: @Meta-Knight Use separator. Duh.

Comment: @AdrianGodong - please improve this answer by giving a simple example. Such as `dict[person.First + "-" + person.Last + "-" + person.DOB]`

Then I think this would receive more upvotes. It really is the most straight forward way.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Wintellect's [PowerCollections](http://www.wintellect.com/PowerCollections.aspx) ([CodePlex download](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections)). I think their MultiDictionary does something like that.

It's a dictionary of dictionaries, so you have 2 keys to access each object, the key for the main dictionary to get you the required sub dictionary, and then the second key for the sub dictionary to get you the required item. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Their `MultiDictionary<,>` allows to assign multiple values to a single key, not to have multiple keys in this sense.

Comment: but OP's question is as vague as it can get. Hence +1 for a different take.

Comment: @pbalaga is right, PowerCollections doesn't allow you to have two keys (downvoted because of that)

Answer (score 5):

Is there anything wrong with

```
new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<object, object>, object>
```

?

Comment: Is there a built-in Pair<T1, T2> class?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue: As of .NET 4.0, there is the [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class.

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong: KVP uses [ValueType.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.gethashcode.aspx) - "If you call the derived type's GetHashCode method, the return value is not likely to be suitable for use as a key in a hash table." KVP is a completely inappropriate choice for a Dictionary key and could yield many collisions.

Answer (score 5):

I've googled for this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/multikey-dictionary.aspx. I guess it's main feature compared to using struct to contain 2 keys in regular dictionary is that you can later reference by one of the keys, instead of having to supply 2 keys.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fleshed out example of a pair class which can be used as the key to a `Dictionary`.

```
public class Pair<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Left { get; private set; }
    public T2 Right { get; private set; }

    public Pair(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        Left = t1;
        Right = t2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Pair<T1, T2>)) return false;
        return Equals((Pair<T1, T2>)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(Pair<T1, T2> obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        return Equals(obj.Left, Left) && Equals(obj.Right, Right);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Left.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ Right.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you use a `Dictionary<TKey1,Dictionary<TKey2,TValue>>`?

You could even subclass this:

```
public class DualKeyDictionary<TKey1,TKey2,TValue> : Dictionary<TKey1,Dictionary<TKey2,TValue>>
```

**EDIT:** This is now a duplicate answer. It also is limited in its practicality. While it does "work" and provide ability to code `dict[key1][key2]`, there are lots of "workarounds" to get it to "just work".

**HOWEVER:** Just for kicks, one could implement Dictionary nonetheless, but at this point it gets a little verbose:

```
public class DualKeyDictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey1, Dictionary<TKey2, TValue>> , IDictionary< object[], TValue >
{
    #region IDictionary<object[],TValue> Members

    void IDictionary<object[], TValue>.Add( object[] key, TValue value )
    {
        if ( key == null || key.Length != 2 )
            throw new ArgumentException( "Invalid Key" );

        TKey1 key1 = key[0] as TKey1;
        TKey2 key2 = key[1] as TKey2;

        if ( !ContainsKey( key1 ) )
            Add( key1, new Dictionary<TKey2, TValue>() );

        this[key1][key2] = value;
    }

    bool IDictionary<object[], TValue>.ContainsKey( object[] key )
    {
        if ( key == null || key.Length != 2 )
            throw new ArgumentException( "Invalid Key" );

        TKey1 key1 = key[0] as TKey1;
        TKey2 key2 = key[1] as TKey2;

        if ( !ContainsKey( key1 ) )
            return false;

        if ( !this[key1].ContainsKey( key2 ) )
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I see, Charles is thinking the same thing. The problem with these is, however, in the allocation. It might be a beast to manage.

Comment: +1 for the naming, DualKey.. Have been looking for a good name :)

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for a `ToMultiKeyDictionary()` here is an implementation that should work with most of the answers here (based on [Herman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15804355/435383)):

```
public static class Extensions_MultiKeyDictionary {

    public static MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, V> ToMultiKeyDictionary<S, K1, K2, V>(this IEnumerable<S> items, Func<S, K1> key1, Func<S, K2> key2, Func<S, V> value) {
        var dict = new MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, V>(); 
        foreach (S i in items) { 
            dict.Add(key1(i), key2(i), value(i)); 
        } 
        return dict; 
    }

    public static MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, V> ToMultiKeyDictionary<S, K1, K2, K3, V>(this IEnumerable<S> items, Func<S, K1> key1, Func<S, K2> key2, Func<S, K3> key3, Func<S, V> value) {
        var dict = new MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, K3, V>(); 
        foreach (S i in items) { 
            dict.Add(key1(i), key2(i), key3(i), value(i)); 
        } 
        return dict; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need a Tuple2 like class.  Be sure that it's GetHashCode() and Equals() is based upon the two contained elements.

See [Tuples in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152019/tuples-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation.  I wanted something to hide the implementation of the Tuple concept.

```
  public class TwoKeyDictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TValue> : Dictionary<TwoKey<TKey1, TKey2>, TValue>
  {
    public static TwoKey<TKey1, TKey2> Key(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2)
    {
      return new TwoKey<TKey1, TKey2>(key1, key2);
    }

    public TValue this[TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2]
    {
      get { return this[Key(key1, key2)]; }
      set { this[Key(key1, key2)] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, TValue value)
    {
      Add(Key(key1, key2), value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2)
    {
      return ContainsKey(Key(key1, key2));
    }
  }

  public class TwoKey<TKey1, TKey2> : Tuple<TKey1, TKey2>
  {
    public TwoKey(TKey1 item1, TKey2 item2) : base(item1, item2) { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return string.Format("({0},{1})", Item1, Item2);
    }
  }
```

It helps keeps the usage looking like a Dictionary

```
item.Add(1, "D", 5.6);

value = item[1, "D"];
```

Comment: how to iterate through all?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example using the Tuple class with the Dictionary.

```
        // Setup Dictionary
    Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string> testDictionary = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>
    {
        {new Tuple<string, string>("key1","key2"), "value1"},
        {new Tuple<string, string>("key1","key3"), "value2"},
        {new Tuple<string, string>("key2","key3"), "value3"}
    };
    //Query Dictionary
    public string FindValue(string stuff1, string stuff2)
    {
        return testDictionary[Tuple.Create(stuff1, stuff2)];
    }
```