# Fast function to return a string based on a key, and vice versa

Tags: c#, .net, string, performance

I need a fast lookup function that will return a string based on an integer key, and also perform the oppose lookup (pass in string, return int).

Should I create 2 hashtables for this?

Comment: If your integer key is compact enough (mostly inclusive of 0 thru N) then I would use string[] or List<string> to map the integers to the string.  As others said, use the Dictionary<string, int> for the reverse.

Answer (score 5):

```
Dictionary<int, string> lookup = new Dictionary<int, string>();
lookup.Add(1, "test1");
lookup.Add(2, "test2");
lookup.Add(3, "test3");
```

If you need to do fast lookups both ways, you could make 2 of them.

Answer (score 4):

A Dictionary is what you want, and plenty of [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-dictionary-is-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171812/multi-key-dictionary-in-c) to help.

Though hardly a definitive answer without more information, will the strings be unique for instance?