# Dictionary with two keys?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am keeping track of values in a console.  Two people "duel" against each other and I was using a dictionary to keep the names recorded along with damage done.

```
var duels = new Dictionary<string, string>();
duels.Add("User1", "50");
duels.Add("User2","34");
```

I'm trying to store both users in the same dictionary row, so it could be verified as User1 is dueling against `User2`. This way if another duel started, it would not interfere with `User1` or `User2`.

```
duels.Add("KeyUser1","KeyUser2","50","34",.../*Other attributes of the duel*/);
```

I need two keys so I can check where the user's damage will go. The damage will always go to the other key--vice versa.
What can I do to make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend using tuples for this. Here is a related article that might lead you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171812/multi-key-dictionary-in-c . Good luck!

Comment: Can a single user be engaged in more than one duel at a time?

Comment: Is the duel involving "User1" and "User2" different than the duel involving "User2" and "User1" ?

Comment: @Branko No they cannot.@David B No not different at all.  Duels against 2 people are interchangeable.

Comment: Tuple may  enforce you to  initialize it at the very beginning but not to inflate it at latter time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Duel
{
  public string User1 {get; protected set;}
  public string User2 {get; protected set;}
  public Duel(string user1, string user2)
  {
    User1 = user1;
    User2 = user2;
  }

  public HashSet<string> GetUserSet()
  {
    HashSet<string> result = new HashSet<string>();
    result.Add(this.User1);
    result.Add(this.User2);
    return result;
  }

  //TODO ... more impl
}
```

Let's make some duels.  `CreateSetComparer` allows the dictionary to use *the values of the set* for equality testing.

```
List<Duel> duelSource = GetDuels();
Dictionary<HashSet<string>, Duel> duels =
  new Dictionary<HashSet<string>, Duel>(HashSet<string>.CreateSetComparer());

foreach(Duel d in duelSource)
{
  duels.Add(d.GetUserSet(), d);
}
```

And finding a duel:

```
HashSet<string> key = new HashSet<string>();
key.Add("User1");
key.Add("User2");
Duel myDuel = duels[key];
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try making a custom data type for the key:

```
class DualKey<T> : IEquatable<DualKey<T>> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    public T Key0 { get; set; }
    public T Key1 { get; set; }

    public DualKey(T key0, T key1)
    {
        Key0 = key0;
        Key1 = key1;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Key0.GetHashCode() ^ Key1.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(DualKey<T> obj)
    {
        return (this.Key0.Equals(obj.Key0) && this.Key1.Equals(obj.Key1))
            || (this.Key0.Equals(obj.Key1) && this.Key0.Equals(obj.Key0));
    }
}
```

Then use a `Dictionary<DualKey<string>, string>`;

Comment: I dont want to sound rude but as per the Stack Overflow norm this should be a comment on the original question and not submitted as an answer. Wouldn't want you to get down voted :)

Comment: I haven't tried an embedded dictionary. Wouldn't that mean having different key dictionaries though?

Answer (score 4):

Something quick.

```
class UserScores {

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public int User1Score { get; set; }
    public int User2Score { get; set; }

    public UserScores(string username1, string username2)
    {
            Key = username1 + ":" + username2;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var userScore = new UserScores("fooUser", "barUser");

    var scores = new Dictionary<string, UserScores>();

    scores.Add(userScore.Key, userScore);

    // Or use a list

    var list = new List<UserScores>();

    list.Add(userScore);

    list.Single (l => l.Key == userScore.Key);
}
```

Although a proper solution in my opinion would use a better thought out UserScores object that tracks that particular "duel" session.

Comment: What if `vin` and `yetish` are fighting while `viny` and `etish` are fighting? :)

Comment: I like the idea of combining them together.  I think I could add something like a `username1+":"+username2` and split the `:` to get `user[0]` and `user[1]`.

Comment: Also @Kyle don't forget to add a GetHashCode() and IEquatable.Equals() implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Since a single person can be involved in at most one duel at a time, you can use a single dictionary to directly "index" **both endpoints** in all duels, something like this:

```
class Duel {

    public Duel(string user1, string user2) {
        Debug.Assert(user1 != user2);
        User1 = user1;
        User2 = user2;
    }

    public readonly string User1;
    public readonly string User2;
    public int User1Score;
    public int User2Score;

}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, Duel>();

        // Add a new duel. A single duel has two keys in the dictionary, one for each "endpoint".
        var duel = new Duel("Jon", "Rob");
        dict.Add(duel.User1, duel);
        dict.Add(duel.User2, duel);

        // Find Jon's score, without knowing in advance whether Jon is User1 or User2:
        var jons_duel = dict["Jon"];
        if (jons_duel.User1 == "Jon") {
            // Use jons_duel.User1Score.
        }
        else {
            // Use jons_duel.User2Score.
        }

        // You can just as easily find Rob's score:
        var robs_duel = dict["Rob"];
        if (robs_duel.User1 == "Rob") {
            // Use robs_duel.User1Score.
        }
        else {
            // Use robs_duel.User2Score.
        }

        // You are unsure whether Nick is currently duelling:
        if (dict.ContainsKey("Nick")) {
            // Yup!
        }
        else {
            // Nope.
        }

        // If Jon tries to engage in another duel while still duelling Rob:
        var duel2 = new Duel("Jon", "Nick");
        dict.Add(duel2.User1, duel); // Exception! Jon cannot be engaged in more than 1 duel at a time.
        dict.Add(duel2.User2, duel); // NOTE: If exception happens here instead of above, don't forget remove User1 from the dictionary.

        // Removing the duel requires removing both endpoints from the dictionary:
        dict.Remove(jons_duel.User1);
        dict.Remove(jons_duel.User2);

        // Etc...

    }

}
```

This is just a basic idea, you might consider wrapping this functionality in your own class...