# Mutiple keys in c# and retrieving associated values

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

These are fixed data structures that I have to work with, I cannot redefine or change them sadly.

I'm looping over a list with each of the objects in the list looking as follows (hover over in Visual Studio).

```
{[ida: 828, idb: 133, XXX.XXX.XXX.MyObject]}
    Key: {ida: 828, idb: 133}
    Value: {XXX.XXX.XXX.MyObject}
```

How would I look up value in this list by key, i.e. say how to a lookup a value given one of the keys such as ida=828. I can get the key-values out as I go through the list, but is there anyway to do this faster? I.e. given 828 I can obtain Value, rather like `ida=828` or `object.key.ida[828]`

One of the issues is these datatypes are not changeable. Any suggestions. Is there only way to get at say ida to loop around all the objects?

I know I can use .Equals to determine whether a key value exists, i.e. `object.key.ida.Equals(828),` but this still leaves the question of getting at the Value. Is this possible?

The data structure looks like the following:

```
Collection<string, Key, Tstuff>

public struct Key
    {
        public long ida;
        public long idb;
    }
```

`Tstuff` is a generic type, but in this case is being passed in the following (effectively the value as above):

```
public struct D2
{
    public float A;
    public float B;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-key dictionary in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171812/multi-key-dictionary-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to accomplish (you don't mention `idb` anywhere in your question), but if the unique combination of `ida` and `idb` is what should get you to the value, then you could use a `Tuple<int, int>` as the key:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, MyObject>();
lookup[Tuple.Create(828, 133)] = MyObjectInstance;
```

However, if your intention is to get at the value given either key (`ida` or `idb`) then you'd be best off just creating two dictionaries:

```
var lookupByA = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();
var lookupByB = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();
lookupByA[828] = MyObjectInstance;
lookupByB[133] = MyObjectInstance;
```

Then you could just check both dictionaries.

Comment: I'm not interested in idb at the moment, that comes along for the ride. These data structures already exist, I'm trying to work with them. I cannot make changes to them.

Comment: What is the data structure? Is that a class? Let's see the actual code that defines the data structure. And how is the list of objects defined? Is it actually a `List<WhateverType>`?

Comment: @itsmen86 I've added more above. Hopefully that should help a little more?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the data structure which you are retrieving your KeyValuePairs from is a dictionary, with a key which is an object made up of two parts - an ida and an idb. If this is the case, you can probably get constant time lookup if you know both parts of the key (ida and idb). Something like:

```
var myObject = theDictionary[new WhateverKeyIsCalled(828, 133)]
```

This assumes that you can actually "new" up the keys in the dictionary, that you know the value of both ida and idb, and that the key has a constructor which takes an ida and an idb. All big assumptions on my part, but I'd need to know more about your problem to give a better answer.

Otherwise you'd have to iterate over each keyvaluepair in your dictionary. Like:

```
foreach(var keyValuePair in theDictionary)
{
     if(keyValuePair.key.ida == 828)
          return keyValuePair.Value;
}
```

This will be O(n) with the number of items in the dictionary (which is a bit silly for a dictionary), and also, you might have multiple values in your dictionary which have an ida of 828, so that could throw a wrench in things.