# What data structure should I use for a double binding between two objects?

Tags: c#, data-structures, binding

I have two lists with two different type of objects each, List list1 and List list2. The object at position `i` in list1 is related with that at position `i` in list2.

I have to answer queries of the type, given an object A return the object B at the same position in list2, and viceversa, given an object B return the object A at the same position in list1.

The trivial solution would be an O(n) search for each query. I'm looking for possible solutions to improve it. So far, what I have are two dictionaries, one `Dictionary<A, B> dicAtoB and Dictionary<B, A> dicBtoA` where I inserted all the elements from the lists in each of them.
I'm asking for some other solutions as in mine the elements are inserted twice, and I have to use this two extra dictionaries and...I don't know what else but I just don't like mine to much.

Comment: Does it TLE? What's the actual problem? I don't think there is a better way unless the objects have some special attribute.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761880/net-dictionary-with-two-keys-and-one-value

Comment: Nop, the speed is ok, but beyond that I also have the concern about good programming practices for the specific case. Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting here and can you post an example input and desired output for it ? Thank you

Comment: Don't try to solve a simple scenario duplicating data without reason. If your list is non-ordered, you find a value with a [linear serch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search). If it's ordered in a meanigful way (e.g. you can define a predecessor and a successor of a given value in the list) use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Since the indexed element has a direct correspondance in the second list, you only need the index. No [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is backed by an array, so you could take advantage of random access. Instead of supplying instance of `A`, supply index `i` (if possible) and get instance of `B` in `O(1)` by invoking `bList[i]`
- extend classes `A` and `B` to include references to the related object from the other class. It would make your insert and remove operations more complex, but search operation will be `O(1)`, which is a justified tradeoff in case that you are doing a lot of search operations