# Adding values to a dictionary that its values are

Tags: c#

I have defined a dictionary that its value is itself a dictionary that the values of that inner dictionary are list of strings like so:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> myDictionary;
```

The structure is complex for me and don't know now how to add values to it and checking if the keys exits, etc..
So I start with:

```
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
    if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey("outerKey"))
    {
        myDictionary.Add("someOuterKey", ???);
    }
```

and then I get stuck. Can you help with writing this?

Comment: where you have `???`, you should probably put an object of type `Dictionary<List<string>>`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  Adding values to myDictionary  !!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-key dictionary in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171812/multi-key-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov probably wanted you to explain what you need such a data structure for. If you actually say what you're trying to store and achieve, others might be able to suggest a less baroque way of doing things. Because dictionaries of dictionaries of lists *are* indeed baroque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to add a value to the outerkey/innerkey structure:

```
var outerKey = "Some Outer Key";
var innerKey = "Some Inner Key";
var myValue = "Some Value";

if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(outerKey))
{
    myDictionary.Add(outerKey, new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
}

if (!myDictionary[outerKey].ContainsKey(innerKey))
{
    myDictionary[outerKey].Add(innerKey, new List<string>());
}

myDictionary[outerKey][innerKey].Add(myValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's quite abstract, might help to make it less abstract and then try and understand it.

Consider that the outer Directory could be "Family", inner directory could be "Member" and List could be "Friends", then it makes sense to do the following:

```
var families = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
var members = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var friends = new List<string> { "Fred", "Arnold", "Rebecca" };
members.Add("John", friends);
families.Add("Smith", members);
```

I always find context helps to work these things out. Just change the names of the variables to whatever makes sense in your project.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you -

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey("outerKey"))
{

    myDictionary.Add("outerKey",  new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
}
```

### Sample Add & Get functions

Once it has been initialized,  here is how u can add a value to it

```
 public void Add(string outerKey, string innerKey, string innerValue)
    {
        //add to out dictionary
        if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey("outerKey"))
        {

            myDictionary.Add("outerKey", new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
        }

        //add to inner dictionary

      if(!myDictionary[outerKey].ContainsKey(innerKey))
      {
          myDictionary[outerKey].Add(innerKey,new List<string>());
      }

        // add to list of inner dictionary
      myDictionary[outerKey][innerKey].Add(innerValue);

    }
```

Check if the keys are added, if not the fetcch shall return null

```
public List<string> FetchValue(string outerKey, string innerKey)
    {
        List<string> result = null;
        if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(outerKey))
            result = myDictionary[outerKey][innerKey];

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: kind of... Now what is the code look like if I want to add some real values to a dictionary?  That just initializes it. Thanks.

Comment: Just because the code complies, doesn't meant that it's useful for the OP

Comment: @Bohn, I've added a sample usage to add values to it. Please write me a comment if any doubt.

Comment: @SamIam, I've added a sample usage, do you think there are some issues in it ?

Comment: @Bohn, Please write me a comment if you require a remove function as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends a little on what you are trying to achieve. There may even be a data structure that would be easier to use. But lets say you want to add `loweststringa` and `loweststringb` for `innerstring1` for `outerstring` (ooohh that is complex).

Then this would do it:

```
List<string> lowestList = new List<string>();
lowestList.AddRange(new[]{"loweststringa", "loweststringb"});

Dictionary<string, List<string>> innerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
innerDictionary.Add("innerstring1", lowestList);

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
myDictionary.Add("outerstring", innerDictionary);
```

The keys you add to `myDictionary` are of type `string`. The values of `myDictionary` are instances of a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

The keys of these inner dictionaries are of course also of type `string` and the values are of type `List<string>`.

If you want to check if "loweststringb" exists in the list for "innerstring1" in the dictionary for "outerstring" you can do the following:

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("outerstring"))
  if (myDictionary["outerstring"].ContainsKey("innerstring1"))
    if (myDictionary["outerstring"]["innerstring1"].Contains("loweststringb"))
      // hooray it's there!
```

But be sure you don't insert `null` references as Dictionaries or Lists in this construction. And the example above is not the most efficient since it iterates through the outermost dictionary three times.

Hope this helps you.

UPDATE: inserting "loweststringc" in the existing list:

```
myDictionary["outerstring"]["innerstring1"].Add("loweststringc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will solve your problem.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey("outerKey"))
{
   var innerDictiionary= new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
   var data= new List<sting>(){
    "hello"
};
innerDictiionary.Add("innerKey", data);
myDictionary.Add("outerKey",  innerDictiionary);
}
```