# how can I make string multidimensional array with string keys and values in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

hi how could I make array like this in c#??:
settings width and height is loaded from file

```
properties["settings"]["width"] = "bbb";
properties["settings"]["height"] = "cccc";
```

and dynamic_string_key is keys loaded from file and I dont know how many or what key name and values will be :)

```
properties["sets_of_data"][dynamic_string_key]= "lalala";
properties["sets_of_data"][dynamic_string_key]= "lalala";
properties["sets_of_data"][dynamic_string_key]= "lalala";
properties["sets_of_data"][dynamic_string_key]= "lalala";
```

Comment: Use either a `Dictionary<string_FirstOuterKey, Dictionary<string_SecondInnerKey, string>>`; but in my opinion it would be better to have some configuration/settings class/object that has two `Dictionary<string, string>`, one for each the "settings" block and one for the "sets_of_data" block. Otherwise, your code might quickly become a mess with all those keys over two levels...

Comment: FTFY `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`

Comment: Your examples don't look like arrays you mean dictionaries/hashtables?

Comment: probably Dictionaries, but for me its arrays :)(Iam php programmer)

Comment: Yeah, but C# is not PHP. If you want to stick with the PHP way of doing things, use PHP. Otherwise, in C# it is dictionaries...

Comment: @Xiaoy312, but I have to specify keys then I cant make random keys with dictionaries? can you give me example. 
I tryed this Dictionary<string_FirstOuterKey, Dictionary<string_SecondInnerKey, string>>
, but it didnt liked dynamic string keys that do not exist when I make dictionary

Comment: So what is best solution to this ?

Comment: Use `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`. I did chose the pseudo-code names there for the string types to highlight their purpose. Sorry if that confused you...

Comment: It is not that "it didnt liked dynamic string keys", but the nested dictionary is not initialized when you try to use it. do this: `properties["a"] = new Dictionary<string, string>(); properties["a"][dynamic_string_key] = "lalala";` note: only initialized it once, or you will lose data.

Comment: For a better solution, use a tuple or value tuple as key in a normal dictionary as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22244631/561113).

Comment: @Xiaoy312 yea probably duplicate, but examples there is unclear for new users, with an example of a question like mine. I know I will get downvotes but is worth it.

Comment: Your question is little bit hard to understand other ways as well. You talk about reading data from file but then you are setting values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C# only allow you to find an element by the index (integer), not by an arbitrary string. In C#, that's a [`Dictionary<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2).

You can use a dictionary of a dictionary, but it's not as easy:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
data["settings"] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
data["settings"]["width"] = "bbb";
```

But that seems overly complicated. If you know you'll have "settings", then it's probably more readable to just have one dictionary for settings:

```
var settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
settings["width"] = "bbb";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is JSON you can use JSON.NET and do it like this

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("foo.json"));
var bar = (string)obj["foo"]["bar"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> properties =
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    {
        "settings",
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"width", "200"},
            {"height", "150"},
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Tuples, especially named tuples

```
var exampleNamedTuple = (Height: 0, Width: 0, Value: "");

var list = new List<(int Height, int Width, string Value)>();
list.Add(exampleNamedTuple);

var height = list.First().Height;
var width = list.First().Width;
var value = list.First().Value;
```

then you can assign it to your settings property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples