# is there a <key, value, value> dictionaryish type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I need something resembling the following:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>, List<DateTime>> = 
             new Dictionary<string, List<int>, List<DateTime>>()
```

are there any built in class in C# which offer something like the above?

**Edit**: for people who can't see why anything like this could ever possibly be useful...

Imagine if you could write something like this:

```
mySuperDictionary SuperDictionary<string, List<int>X, List<int>Y> .....

myXvalues = mySuperDictionary["myKey"].X;
myYvalues = mySuperDictionary["myKey"].Y;
```

personally I think that would be a pretty neat.

Comment: how about putting the int and the DateTime in a struct/class?

Comment: How exactly is this meant to be used? I cannot even theorize a situation where this would be useful. Perhaps you want to lookup an int and datetime for each string.. yes?

Comment: Posting the code you want to compile is not very helpful. Tell us what behavior you want out of such a data structure.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No.

Create a Pair or Tuple type yourself.

Something like:

```
class Pair<T,V>
{
  T First{get; set;}
  V Second{get; set;}
}
```

Then you can declare a `Dictionary<string, Pair<List<int>, List<DateTime>>`.

Comment: Its worth noting that in .NET 4.0 there is/will be a Tuple type.  So this answer will be out of date shortly for those of us on the cutting edge.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152019/will-a-future-version-of-net-support-tuples-in-c/1047961#1047961

Answer (score 9):

I do not believe so. I think it would be better if you made a custom object to hold your `List<int>` and `List<DateTime>` objects.

```
Dictionary<string, CustomClass>> =  new Dictionary<string, CustomClass>();

public class CustomClass
{
   public List<int> IntegerList { get; set; }
   public List<DateTime> DateTimeList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Normally, you'd just do:

```
Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<List<int>,List<DateTime>>> dictionary;
```

A custom class is usaully nicer, however, for this type of thing.  Having `Dictionary<Key, Value, Value>` doesn't really add any value - it's still a single key -> *something* lookup, so just make your value handle it.

Answer (score 0):

There are not built in class as your requirement but you can create your own.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to roll your own. This could be easily done with a simple struct or class. [This answer has good information on how to do something like this using tuples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152019/will-a-future-version-of-net-support-tuples-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a generic Pair<> class in the framework, which you could use to associate two "values" with each other.

Comment: There is `KeyValuePair`2` in .NET 2.0, but it is ugly because it has a very long name and it has other meanings associated with it. In .NET 4.0 there's the series of `Tuple` classes.

Comment: Duly noted. I've used the KeyValuePair previously; it is a bit clunky, and has a certain implied meaning, besides just "Pair". I'll see what I can find about the Tuple you mentioned.

Comment: rolling your own Tuple is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly typed datatable could produce the same data (and structure) you need. See below.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TypedDataTable.aspx