# get current process name with file extension in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

GetAllProccess Function Return All Runing Proccesses In Windows. I want to get current proccess name which extension is `".avi", ".mkv", ".mpg", ".mp4", ".wmv"`
e.g. if I play any video file in windows media player it return (wmplayer.exe) or if I play any video file in KM PLAYER it returns(kmplayer.exe)
Thanks
here is my code this code working very slow
reference http://vmccontroller.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/47386#195318

string filename;
            Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses() ;
            foreach (Process prc in procs)
            {

```
            if (procs.Length > 0)
            {
                int id = prc.Id;
                IEnumerator<FileSystemInfo> fie = DetectOpenFiles.GetOpenFilesEnumerator(id);

                while (fie.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (fie.Current.Extension.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == ".mp3")
                    {
                        filename = fie.Current.FullName;
                        break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit While
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Those are data files not processes.

Comment: if those data file runing it shows proccess name

Comment: You might want to look at accessed files, something like filemon ?

Comment: @user757321, please don't ask open-ended questions [http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start by taking a look at [Handle By Mark Russinovich](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx). Just run it as administrator and it will return all files used by all processes.

You could use the following syntax to put the results into a text file:

```
handle.exe > log.txt
```

Afterwards, you may use `PowerShell` to extract the information about the processes using those data files:

```
Get-Content log.txt | 
    where{$_.readcount -gt 6} | 
    foreach{
        if($_.Substring(0,1) -ne " " -and $_.Substring(0,1) -ne "-")
        {$process = $_.ToString()}
        elseif($_.ToLower() -like "*.avi" `
            -or $_.ToLower() -like "*.mkv" `
            -or $_.ToLower() -like "*.mpg" `
            -or $_.ToLower() -like "*.mp4" `
            -or $_.ToLower() -like "*.wmv" `
            )
        {$process.ToString()}
    }
```

Here's the same approach from C# (you need to run the application as Administrator):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processes = GetProcesses();

        // enumerate the processes
        foreach (Tuple<int,string> mediaFile in processes.Distinct())
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(i => i.Id == mediaFile.Item1).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) uses {2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, mediaFile.Item2);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<Tuple<int,string>> GetProcesses()
    {
        string line = "";
        int counter = 0;
        string currentProcess = "";
        List<Tuple<int, string>> mediaFiles = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

        Process compiler = new Process();
        compiler.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\YourPath\Handle.exe";
        compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        compiler.Start();

        while ((line = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // skipping applicaion info
            if (++counter > 6)
            {
                if (!" -".Contains(char.Parse(line.Substring(0, 1))))
                {
                    currentProcess = line;
                }
                else if ((new[] { ".avi", ".mkv", ".mpg", ".mp4", ".wmv" })
                    .Contains(line.ToLower().Substring(line.Length - 4)))
                {
                    int pos = currentProcess.IndexOf("pid:") + 5;
                    string pid = currentProcess.Substring(pos, currentProcess.IndexOf(" ", pos) - pos);
                    mediaFiles.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(Int32.Parse(pid),line.Substring(21)));
                }
            }
        }
        compiler.WaitForExit();

        return mediaFiles;
    }
}
```

Comment: handle.exe return all files and proccess i need only those proccess with run video files

Comment: thnaks alex this is good but how can i use this from my c# application

Comment: here is my code string filename;
            Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses() ;
            foreach (Process prc in procs)
            {
                  
                if (procs.Length > 0)
                {
                    int id = prc.Id; IEnumerator<FileSystemInfo> fie = DetectOpenFiles.GetOpenFilesEnumerator(id);
 while (fie.MoveNext())
                    {
                        if (fie.Current.Extension.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == ".mp3")  {
                            filename = fie.Current.FullName;
                            break; Exit While  }

Comment: this code get all proccess and working very slowly

Comment: alex greate and thanks once again please see me update question i some search and found good code but this code also slow working issue

Comment: Please mark my answer if it helped you to find a solution for your original problem.

Comment: alex is it possible handle.exe work silently i mean no dos windows open

Comment: Just add 'compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;'.

Comment: and how to get current name of file in proccess

Comment: private static List<Tuple<int,string>> GetProcesses() tuple could not found

Comment: You have to use .NET Framework 4.0 or newer, or you could also write a similar class: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4312277/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4312277/674700).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24372/discussion-between-user757321-and-alex-filipovici)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to do is enumerate all processes and find the process
to which your handle belongs to.
..NET doesn't provide the AFI for this, you need to dive deeper, more deep
then WINAPI - to the nt.dll level, where you can find undocumented ZwQueryObject().

Using this methods is not a simple task, because it returns name and info
about handle belonging to the YOUR process.
So, you need to perform additional task - use DuplicateHandle() to bring
external handle to your process.

I recomend you to study this sample [http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/syst...icle.php/c2827](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/system/processesmodules/article.php/c2827)

which provide all functional u requre.