# Check what programs are playing audio?

Tags: c#, audio, process

I am making a program and I want to find and mute programs that are playing audio so all you hear is mine.

(This is an option for the program, nothing malicious about it)

I have looked it up and I cannot seem to find a way to check what programs are playing audio (Much like windows does)

I don't have any code examples of attempting this because id has no idea.

In case someone misses reads or I don't word the above sentences correct I would like to find **EVERY** process with audio playing and either **KILL** or **MUTE** the process

Comment: I'll look into it but i have never seen code that does something like that

Comment: Wouldnt that mean you need to have api access to these active programs?

Comment: Maybe, i mean does windows when they get all the current sounds from programs?

Answer (score 3):

If you can get [Peak meters for individual programs on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313692/peak-meters-for-individual-programs-on-windows-7), you can identify sessions and applications. `IAudioSessionControl` interface offers you muting options similar to what user can do via standard Volume Mixer application (session muting in particular).

Answer (score 0):

There was a pretty similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828440/get-current-process-name-with-file-extension-in-c-sharp/14828598#14828598), maybe the same approach I posted in my answer would fit your scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14828598/674700. What you'd need to change are the types of files (into `.mp3`, `.wav` and so on) and kill the processes found, with the exception of your application's.

The drawbacks: you'll need to run your application as administrator and it also requires a third party console app.

Comment: Not quite what im looking for but ill give it a go.