# Mixed Arrays in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

Is it possible to create a Mixed Array in both C++ and C#

I mean an array that contains both chars and ints?

ex:

```
Array [][] = {{'a',1},{'b',2},{'c',3}};
```

Comment: A char is an integer type in C++

Answer (score 12):

**Neither C# nor C++ support creating this kind of data structure using native arrays**, however you could create a `List<Tuple<char,int>>` in C# or a `std::vector<std::pair<char,int>>` in C++.

You could also consider using the `Dictionary<>` or `std::map<>` collections if one of the elements can be considered a unique key, and the order of the elements is unimportant but only their association.

For the case of lists (rather than dictionaries), in C# you would write:

```
List<Tuple<char,int>> items = new List<Tuple<char,int>>();

items.Add( new Tuple<char,int>('a', 1) );
items.Add( new Tuple<char,int>('b', 2) );
items.Add( new Tuple<char,int>('c', 3) );
```

and in C++ you would write:

```
std::vector<std::pair<char,int>> items;  // you could typedef std::pair<char,int>
items.push_back( std::pair<char,int>( 'a', 1 ) );
items.push_back( std::pair<char,int>( 'b', 2 ) );
items.push_back( std::pair<char,int>( 'c', 3 ) );
```

Comment: instead of std::pair<char,int>( 'a', 1 ) you could just use std::make_pair('a', 1), which the stdlib provides for your convenience :)

Comment: Why couldn't he make an array of pairs/tuples? Is there some reason I'm not seeing why his only option is to switch to List/vector?

Comment: @jalf STL-driven containers are likely to be less error-prone that generic arrays.

Comment: True. I'm just pointing out that the "minimal" solution to the OP's problem would be to use tuple/pair. Changing the container type is irrelevant to the question, whether or not it is safer. I just think that if an answer changes the premise, it should have a good reason to do so, and explain it clearly.

Answer (score 5):

In `C++` you would have to use something like `std::vector<boost::tuple< , , >` or `std::vector<std::pair>` if you only have two elements in each tuple.

Example for the `C++` case:

```
typedef std::pair<int, char> Pair;

std::vector<Pair> pairs;

pairs.push_back(Pair(0, 'c'));
pairs.push_back(Pair(1, 'a'));
pairs.push_back(Pair(42, 'b'));
```

*Extended example for the `C++` case (using `boost::assign`).*

```
using boost::assign;

std::vector<Pair> pairs;

pairs += Pair(0, 'c'), Pair(1, 'a'), Pair(42, 'b');
```

---

For `C#` you may want to see [**this.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152019/will-a-future-version-of-net-support-tuples-in-c)

Comment: can you give an example on how to achieve this?

Comment: std::vector<std::pair> preferred

Answer (score 0):

In C# and C++ it's not possible to create an array of mixed types. You should use other classes like std::vector in C++ or Dictionary <char, int> in C#.

Answer (score 0):

A classic array (the one with the brackets) can only have one type, which is part of its declaration (like int[] nums). There is no Array[].