# Multiple type array

Tags: java, arrays

I am working with an array and need some help.  I would like to create an array where the first field is a String type and the second field is an Integer type.
For result:

Console out

```
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

Comment: what have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393027/mixed-arrays-in-c-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An array can only have a single type.
You can create a new class like:

```
Class Foo{
   String f1;
   Integer f2;
}

Foo[] array=new Foo[10];
```

You might also be interested in using a map (it seems to me like you're trying to map strings to ids).

EDIT:
You could also define your array of type Object but that's something i'd usually avoid.

Answer (score 10):

You could create an array of type object and then when you print to the console you invoke the `toString()` of each element.

```
Object[] obj = new Object[]{"a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3};
for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(obj[i].toString() + " ");
}
```

Will yield:

> a 1 b 2 c 3

Answer (score 1):

```
Object[] randArray = new Object [3]; 
randArray[0] = new Integer(5);
randArray[1] = "Five";
randArray[2] = new Double(5.0);

for(Object obj : randArray) {
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Object[] myArray = new Object[]{"a", 1, "b", 2 ,"c" , 3};

    for (Object element : myArray) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object [] field = new Object[6];
field[0] = "a";
field[1] = 1;
field[2] = "b";
field[3] = 2;
field[4] = "c";
field[5] = 3;
for (Object o: field)
  System.out.print(o);
```

Comment: @xmoex: The solution is okay except here the array is being initialized in crude way.

Comment: this Object[] myArray = new Object[]{"a", 1, "b", 2 ,"c" , 3}; is just syntactic sugar and for this question is my solution fine.

Comment: no offense, but imho I'd consider this bad coding style as it ignores the pairwise occurrence of string and integer per item

Answer (score -4):

try using Vector instead of Array.

Comment: This answer does not address the question in the slightest!