# Is it possible to create a mixed array in vala?

Tags: vala

In Vala I see that when I declare an array I have to specify the type, like

```
int[] myarray = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

I wonder if there is a way to have a mixed array like

```
smtg[] myarray = { 1, 'two', 3 };
```

I see that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393027/mixed-arrays-in-c-and-c-sharp)  they say that in *C++* and *C#* it's not possible but I just started learning vala and I have no background with any *C*-like language so I want to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

That said, you can create an array of something that can hold other types, like `GLib.Value` or `GLib.Variant`, and Vala can automatically convert to/from those two, so you could do something like

```
GLib.Value[] values = {
  1,
  "two",
  3.0
}
```

It's usually a terrible idea (you're basically throwing away compile time type safety), but you can do it.

Comment: The code gets compiled. Great ... but now ... how do I print such an array? I don't understand how I can set a type for the item in the foreach loop. http://pastebin.com/iZXpgQuK <- This is obviously wrong

Comment: I can't give a full answer in this little box, but basically you would need to do something like `foreach (GLib.Value value in values) { if (value.holds (typeof(int))) stdout.printf ("%d", (int) value); else if (value.holds (typeof(string))) stdout.printf ("%s", (string) value); } }`.  You would probably also want to add some error checking in case it was a type you didn't expect.  For GValue there is also a mechanism to transform from one type to another, and most simple types should have support for transforming to a string built in.  See GLib.Value.type_transformable and transform.