# Have I implemented Y-combinator using C# dynamic, and if I haven't, what is it?

Tags: c#, dynamic, functional-programming, y-combinator

My brain seems to be in masochistic mode, so after being drowned in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx), [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx) and [this](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html), it wanted to mess around with some DIY in C#.

I came up with the following, which I don't *think* is the Y-combinator, but it *does* seem to manage to make a non-recursive function recursive, without referring to itself:

```
Func<Func<dynamic, dynamic>, Func<dynamic, dynamic>> Y = x => x(x);
```

So given these:

```
Func<dynamic, Func<dynamic, dynamic>> fact = 
                  self => n => n == 0 ? 1 : n * self(self)(n - 1);
Func<dynamic, Func<dynamic, dynamic>> fib = 
                  self => n => n < 2 ? n : self(self)(n-1) + self(self)(n-2);
```

We can generate these:

```
Func<dynamic, dynamic> Fact = Y(fact);
Func<dynamic, dynamic> Fib = Y(fib);

Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("Fact({0})={1}", i, Fact(i)));

Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("Fib({0})={1}", i, Fib(i)));
```

Comment: This is **U** combinator: `U x = x x` in combinators notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's not the Y combinator; you're only halfway there. You still need to factor out the self-application within the "seed" functions you're applying it to. That is, instead of this:

```
Func<dynamic, Func<dynamic, dynamic>> fact = 
                  self => n => n == 0 ? 1 : n * self(self)(n - 1);
```

you should have this:

```
Func<dynamic, Func<dynamic, dynamic>> fact = 
                  self => n => n == 0 ? 1 : n * self(n - 1);
```

Note the single occurrence of `self` in the second definition as opposed to the two occurrences in the first definition.

(edited to add:) BTW, since your use of C# simulates the lambda calculus with call-by-value evaluation, the fixed-point combinator you want is [the one often called Z, not Y](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator#Other_fixed_point_combinators)

(edited again to elaborate:) The equation that describes `Y` is this (see [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator#Y_combinator) for the derivation):

```
Y g = g (Y g)
```

But in most practical programming languages, you evaluate the argument of a function before you call the function. In the programming languages community, that's called call-by-value evaluation (not to be confused with the way C/C++/Fortran/etc programmers distinguish "call by value" vs "call by reference" vs "call by copy-restore", etc).

But if we did that, we'd get

```
Y g = g (Y g) = g (g (Y g)) = g (g (g (Y g))) = ...
```

That is, we'd spend all of our time *constructing* the recursive function and never get around to *applying* it.

In call-by-name evaluation, on the other hand, you apply a function, here `g`, to the unevaluated argument expression, here `(Y g)`. But if `g` is like `fact`, it's waiting for another argument before it does anything. So we would wait for the second argument to `g` before trying to evaluate `(Y g)` further---and depending on what the function does (ie, if it has a base case), we might not need to evaluate `(Y g)` at all. That's why `Y` works for call-by-name evaluation.

The fix for call-by-value is to change the equation. Instead of `Y g = g (Y g)`, we want something like the following equation instead:

```
Z g = g (λx. (Z g) x)
```

(I think I got the equation right, or close to right. You can calculate it out and see if it fits with the definition of `Z`.)

One way to think of this is instead of computing "the whole recursive function" and handing it to `g`, we hand it a function that will compute the recursive function a little bit at a time---and only when we actually need a bit more of it so we can apply it to an argument (`x`).

Comment: I there any chance you could elaborate on your BTW? It's slightly over the top of my head (but then most of this is...)

Comment: Thanks for the further elaboration - I was being confused by the interpretation of call-by-value. I just got as far as your recursive example (`Z = f => f(f(f(f)));` will work for as many `f`'s as I include...), now working on going the next step...

Comment: Yes, that's another way to look at the fixed point of `f`: as the limit of the sequence {`⊥`, `f(⊥)`, `f(f(⊥))`, `f(f(f(⊥)))`, ...}, where `⊥` is a function that fails to terminate, or blows up, or whatever.

Comment: Problem with most people in academics is that they don't understand the implications of using X, Y and Z as example variable names.